# Append to the same class with condition?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this. Now, I want to replace old value in class name "content" with condition : if the value in which class coincides with one of the value in Array below, then append to it like : (See example)

```
<div class="content">style1</div>
<div class="content">Stackover</div>
<div class="content">style3</div>
<div class="content">somthing</div>
<div class="content">style1</div>

<script>
var styletodisplay = ["style1", "style2", "style3"];
for(m = 0; m < styletodisplay.length; m++)
{
    //if the value get from class "content" coincides with one of the value in Array then append to that class(not for all) with HTML : <p>styleN is added</p>
   //For example : if the value get from class "content" is style3, then you need to append to that class a HTML like : <p>style3 is added</p>
}
</script>
```

It means, we have result :

```
    <div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
    <div class="content">Stackover</div>
    <div class="content"><p>style3 is added</p></div>
    <div class="content">somthing</div>
    <div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
```

How can I do that? I know we should use "ID" for unique but HTML code is block, only class is allowed. Help me for this. Thanks

Comment: Look in the DOM element's contents? What's the specific issue?

Comment: @DaveNewton: just replace if that class have one of the value in Array.

Answer (score 2):

Html and script:

```
<div class="content">style1</div>
<div class="content">Stackover</div>
<div class="content">style3</div>
<div class="content">somthing</div>
<div class="content">style1</div>

<script>
// Append containts() function to all array
Array.prototype.contains = function(obj) {
    var i = this.length;
    while (i--) {
        if (obj === this[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// Get all div .content
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".content");

var styletodisplay = ["style1", "style2", "style3"];
for(m = 0; m < els.length; ++m) {
    var inner = els[m].innerHTML;

    // if inner div is one of styletodisplay
    if(styletodisplay.contains(inner)) {
        els[m].innerHTML = '<p>' + inner + ' is added</p>';
    }
}
</script>
```

Result in HTML:

```
<div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
<div class="content">Stackover</div>
<div class="content"><p>style3 is added</p></div>
<div class="content">somthing</div>
<div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
```

The JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Rgdy/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I am trying with your answer.

Comment: Sorry. If I want result like <script>var = "style1"; </script>, then How to do? Thanks for your help again.

Comment: instead of `<p>style1 is added</p>` ?

Comment: yes. I want <div class="content"><script>var styletodisplay = "style1";</script></div>. Thanks you so much.

Comment: You are welcome, don't forget to validate the answer if it's what you want :)

Comment: why script does not run? It is broken.

Comment: Because you inject some script. If you want to see `<script...` you need to parse some html special chars.

Comment: Ok but this is not a chat. So here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BafS/4Rgdy/2/

Comment: It just for display text, it's not for run script. Maybe, els[m].innerHTML cannot add and run <script>....

Comment: Yes before ! But I really don't understand why you want this. If you want to inject something, do it in javascript directly like http://jsfiddle.net/BafS/4Rgdy/4/

Comment: Sorry for bother you. I want run a script like this (but with condition above) http://jsfiddle.net/R5xad/6/

Comment: I think that you may learn a bit more javascript. Is it what you expected http://jsfiddle.net/BafS/4Rgdy/5/ alert inner div ?

Answer (score 1):

My own approach (though it requires an up-to-date browser):

```
function addFoundStyle(el, styles){
    var textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        text = el[textProp].trim(),
        para = document.createElement('p'),
        foundAt = styles.indexOf(text);
    if (foundAt > -1) {
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles[foundAt] + ' is added'));
        el.classList.add(styles[foundAt]);
        el.appendChild(para);
    }
}

styles = ['style1', 'style3'];

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.content'), function(a){
    addFoundStyle(a, styles);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AXbqM/).

If you'd prefer to replace the text-content of the element (rather than append a paragraph to the element):

```
function addFoundStyle(el, styles){
    var textProp = 'textContent' in document ? 'textContent' : 'innerText',
        text = el[textProp].trim(),
        para = document.createElement('p'),
        foundAt = styles.indexOf(text);
    if (foundAt > -1) {
        para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(styles[foundAt] + ' is added'));
        el.classList.add(styles[foundAt]);
        el.replaceChild(para, el.firstChild);
    }
}

styles = ['style1', 'style3'];

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('div.content'), function(a){
    addFoundStyle(a, styles);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AXbqM/1/).

Incidentally, a simple jQuery solution:

```
var styles = ['style1','style2','style3'];

$('div.content').text(function(i,t){
    var text = $.trim(t),
        style = styles.indexOf(text);
    $(this).addClass(styles[style]);
    return style > -1 ? styles[style] + ' is added' : t;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/AXbqM/2/).

References:

- JavaScript

  - [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
  - [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).
  - [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
  - [`document.createTextNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createTextNode).
  - [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelectorAll).
  - [`Element.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList).
  - [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
  - [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.replaceChild).
  - [`'property' in Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in).
  - [`String.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim).
- jQuery:

  - [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
  - [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Comment: Sorry. If I want result like <script>var = "style1"; </script>, then How to do? Thanks David again.

Comment: You mean how could you use a string, instead of an array? (While I'm happy to help it will, now, have to be tomorrow; I'm afraid I need sleep right now, I'm sorry to say).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some jQuery:

**Here's a fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/D6SxQ/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">style1</div>
<div class="content">Stackover</div>
<div class="content">style3</div>
<div class="content">somthing</div>
<div class="content">style1</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var styletodisplay = ["style1", "style2", "style3"];

$('.content').each(function(i,el){
    var pos = styletodisplay.indexOf($(el).text());
    if (pos > -1) {
        $(this).html("<p>" + styletodisplay[pos] + " is added</p>");
    }
});
```

**Result**

```
<div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
<div class="content">Stackover</div>
<div class="content"><p>style3 is added</p></div>
<div class="content">somthing</div>
<div class="content"><p>style1 is added</p></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sorry. If I want result like <div class="content"><script>var styletodisplay = "style1";</script></div>. How to do?

Comment: Are you sure you want script blocks in each of your DOM elements? That is highly unusual. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you just trying to append a class to each content block? Something more like <div class='content style1'>style1</div>

Comment: It sounds like you want something like this: [http://jsfiddle.net/Wp6es/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/Wp6es/1/)